# Kerio alternative to EWS?

Tags: exchange-2010, kerio, exchange

I have recently developed some software that provides a php interface to read and write some calendars on an Outlook 2010 server. This uses EWS (Exchange Web Services) extensively.

Now I have been asked to adapt it to work with a Kerio Mail Server. Currently Kerio does not have support for EWS, although they have hinted that it might be forthcoming, so does anyone know of a Kerio alternative to EWS which is quite similar and wouldn't require too much code rewriting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you wait a few more weeks? According to their corporate blog Kerio Connect 7.2 will support EWS and a beta is coming soon:

> Development work is well under way for full synchronization of Outlook 2011 and Kerio Connect using the Exchange Web Services architecture, and it will be part of the upcoming new version.
>
> As is customary with us, we will publish several beta versions of Kerio Connect 7.2. The first public one will be ready in about a month, and will revolve around CalDAV and CardDAV, as well as feature an early preview of EWS for Outlook 2011.

Source: [Blog entry dated 30-Sep-2010](http://www.kerio.com/blog/kerio-connect-and-outlook-2011-mac)

If you absolutely can’t wait, you could try the old [HTTP-DAV method](http://www.msexchange.org/articles/Access-Exchange-2000-2003-Mailbox-WebDAV.html) that is used by Entourage to talk to Exchange (and Kerio).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your answer. I have actually been using WebDAV in the mean time, as it means I will also have support for Exchange 2003. But it is good to know that Kerio will have EWS support soonish, that way I won't have to handle 2 different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no support for EWS in any version of Kerio right now. However, it does support iCal. Could your software work with that instead?

Comment: Hmmm, not sure, can I use iCal in php to communicate with the mail server?